# Does Electrum provides any API?

Tags: api, electrum, bip32-hd-wallets, bitcoin-cash

Does Electrum provides any API? If yes, please let me know if there's any dedicated documentation available.

Also, does Electrum support Bitcoin Cash?

Purpose:
I want to integrate Electrum into my application for wallet service and seeding capabilities. I'm planning to run full node for BCH and BTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes for sure, You can send requests to electrum servers or your server (recommended) by sending JSON-RPC requests.

Take a look on Electrum documentation

https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html

for bitcoin cash use `Electroncash`  same commands work.

For example, to broadcast a hex transaction you can call

`{"id": 1, "method": "blockchain.transaction.broadcast", "params": ["YOUR_HEX_TRANSACTION"]}`

There are no wallet commands available, but blockchain commands.

Comment: Adam, Thanks for the answer. I was also looking for a similar solution asked by Gagan.
I have further questions, like there is bitcore api sdk is also available to create wallets and do transactions. Then what benefit do we get to use electrum api's? I will really appericate the answer :)

Comment: Thanks but I didn't found any method that says createWallet :/

Comment: amit You will need an Electrum client that connects to an Electrum server. It is similar in logic to the bitcore api, but requires less components and is more secure by storing all wallet/key stuff on the client.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in the comments section. anyway, I've edited my answer.